# sending data from a "form action" to a views function in django

Tags: html, django

How are you community, I'm a little confused between my newbies and lack of knowledge, I'm working on a small project in Django and I'm also trying to send data from a form action in the html to another view function but I'm not understanding it well How does this work and on top of that I have to send several data not just one and it confuses me even more, I have the following HTML:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<main class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 mt-5">
            <form action="/interface/" method="POST" class="card card-body">

                <h1>Interface</h1>
                <h4>{{ error }}</h4>
                <select  name="dv">
                    <option selected disabled="True">Select Device</option>
                    {% for device in devicess %}
                        <option>{{ device.id }} - {{ device.name }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <br>
                {% csrf_token %}

                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </form>
                <br>
            {% for interface in interfaces %}       
            <section class="card card-body">
                
                <h2>{{interface.Interface}}</h2>

                {% if interface.Description == "" %} 
                    <p class="text-secondary">none description</p>
                {% else %} 
                    <P class="text-secondary">{{interface.Description}}</P>                     
                {% endif %}
            
                <form  action= "{% url 'send_description' %}"method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="text" name="command" class="form-control" placeholder="Change description">
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary align-content-lg-center">Send change</button>
                </form>

                <br>

                {% if interface.Status == "up" %} 
                    <p class="text-secondary">Interface State:  Free</p>
                {% else %} 
                    <p class="text-secondary">Interface State:  Used</p>
                {% endif %}

                
            </section>
                <br>
            {% endfor %}    
            
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

{% endblock %}
```

and aesthetically to better understand the first POST executed like this:

[image]

So far everything is perfect, if I press the "Send change" button it redirects me perfectly, the problem is that I need to send various data such as device.id, interface to that function that I am executing in the action= "{% url 'send_description' %} .Interface and also the content of the input that is inside the same form. Could you give me a hand or a guide on where to find the best way?

regards!

Comment: There is few ways you can do this. 1) You send async with help of ajax. 2) you send it to the same function that renders that view then redirect or stay on this page.(I would do this) 3) You send to another function which renders another page and deals with post.

Comment: Thank you very much @Danijel, according to your recommendation of option 2, could you give me an example of the best way to do this? I've used `<select name="dv">` but I'm not sure if it's the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by saying that this would work way better with JS and AJAX. But, to answer your question, data is passed via Django [http request object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/), in your case, since you have several different forms, it is possible to pass this data by adding a hidden field inside each form with the desired value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="interface" value="{{ interface.id }}">
```

And fetch this value form the request object in the view:

```
interface = request.POST.get('interface')
```

A full example:

models.py

```
class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Interface(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='interface description field')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='interfaces')
```

views.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

def list_interfaces(request):
    devices = Device.objects.all()
    interfaces = None

    try:
        selected_device = Device.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('dv'))
        interfaces = selected_device.interfaces.all()

    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        selected_device = Device.objects.all().first()
        if selected_device:
            interfaces = selected_device.interfaces.all()
        else:
            selected_device = None

    context = {
        'devices': devices,
        'selected_device': selected_device,
        'interfaces': interfaces
    }
    return render(request, 'list_device_interfaces.html', context)

def send_description(request):
    command = request.POST.get('command')
    device = request.POST.get('seleted_device')
    interface = request.POST.get('interface')
    print(f'command: {command}')
    print(f'device_id: {device}')
    print(f'device_id: {interface}')
    return redirect('core:list-device-interfaces')
```

urls.py

```
from core import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path("list/device/interfaces/" , views.list_interfaces, name="list-device-interfaces"),
    path("send/description/" , views.send_description, name="send-description"),
]
```

list_device_interfaces.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<main class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 mt-5">
            <form action="{% url 'core:list-device-interfaces' %}" method="POST" class="card card-body">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <h1>Device</h1>
                <h4>{{ error }}</h4>
                <select  name="dv">
                    <option selected disabled="True">Select Device</option>
                    {% for device in devices %}
                        <option value="{{ device.id }}" {% if device.id == selected_device.id %} selected {% endif %}>{{ device.id }} - {{ device.name }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <br>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </form>
                <br>
            <hr>
            <h2>Interfaces</h2>
            {% for interface in interfaces %}       
            <section class="card card-body">
                
                <h2>{{interface.name}}</h2>

                {% if interface.description == "" %} 
                    <p class="text-secondary">none description</p>
                {% else %} 
                    <P class="text-secondary">{{interface.description}}</P>                     
                {% endif %}
            
                <form  action= "{% url 'core:send-description' %}"method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="text" name="command" class="form-control" placeholder="Change description">
                    <input type="hidden" name="seleted_device" value="{{ selected_device.id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="interface" value="{{ interface.id }}">
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary align-content-lg-center">Send change</button>
                </form>

                <br>

                {% if interface.status %} 
                    <p class="text-secondary">Interface State:  Free</p>
                {% else %} 
                    <p class="text-secondary">Interface State:  Used</p>
                {% endif %}

                
            </section>
                <br>
            {% endfor %}
            
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Niko for your help, it cost me a lot to be able to analyze your answer, you were very clear but being quite new it still takes me time to analyze, although I did not strictly use your solution, you helped me a lot to be able to find a solution to my problem!

I basically made use of input tags `<input type="hidden" name="xxx" value="{{xxx}}">`

thanks and regards!